# type casting in laravel json response in relationships eager loading

Tags: laravel, casting, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

This is my post model.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['title','featuring_image', 'brief', 'body', 'seen_count'];


    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }



    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function someComments()
    {
        return $this->comments()->limit(Constants::COMMENTS_COUNT_LIMIT);
    }

    public function commentsCount()
    {
        return $this->comments()
            ->selectRaw('post_id, count(*) as count')
            ->groupBy('post_id');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }

    public function isLiked()
    {
        return $this->likes()->where('user_id', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 0);
    }

    public function likesCount()
    {
        return $this->likes()
            ->selectRaw('post_id, count(*) as count')
            ->groupBy('post_id');
    }


}
```

I executed this query on this model.

```
 $post = Post::with(['categories', 'user', 'commentsCount', 'likesCount', 'isLiked'])->find($post->id);
```

Because of the relation between this table and like and comment table, The output of this query for `'commentsCount', 'likesCount', 'isLiked'` is an array. But I need to receive numbers for `'commentsCount'` and `'likesCount'`, and a boolean for `'isliked'` as an output, in laravel josn response.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson  
laravel v5.4.35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to use the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) the comes with Eloquent instead.

Then for `is_liked` you could use a scope to get the value and the `cast` it to a boolean:

```
public function scopeIsLiked($query)
{
    if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
        $query->select([$query->getQuery()->from . '.*']);
    }

    $relation = Relation::noConstraints(function () {
        return $this->likes();
    });

    $q = $this->likes()->getRelationExistenceCountQuery(
        $relation->getRelated()->where('user_id', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 0)->newQuery(), $query
    );

    $query->selectSub($q->toBase(), 'is_liked');
}
```

Please note you will need to add the `use` statement for `Relation` to the top of the class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
```

You model could then look like:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'featuring_image', 'brief', 'body', 'seen_count'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function someComments()
    {
        return $this->comments()->limit(Constants::COMMENTS_COUNT_LIMIT);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }

    /**
     * Scope to add the "is_liked" flag.
     *
     * @param $query
     */
    public function scopeIsLiked($query)
    {
        if (is_null($query->getQuery()->columns)) {
            $query->select([$query->getQuery()->from . '.*']);
        }

        $relation = Relation::noConstraints(function () {
            return $this->likes();
        });

        $q = $this->likes()->getRelationExistenceCountQuery(
            $relation->getRelated()->where('user_id', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 0)->newQuery(), $query
        );

        $query->selectSub($q->toBase(), 'is_liked');
    }
}
```

And your query would look something like:

```
$post = Post::with('categories', 'user')
    ->withCount('likes', 'comments')
    ->isLiked()
    ->find($post->id);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel casts:
Inside the each model you can add the following to cast a value, per example:

```
protected $casts = [
   'isLiked' => 'boolean',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rwd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45937652/4516316) gives a nice solution using scopes, but for laravel 5.4+ you could get away with aliasing the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) result and then casting it to boolean with a [`$cast`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) variable on the model or an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) (with accessor, you can only get snake case `is_liked`). This way we don't need to write complex scopes.

The model would be

```
class Post extends Model
{
    // rest of model 

    protected $casts = ['isLiked'=>'boolean'];

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$post = Post::with('categories', 'user')
    ->withCount(
        [
            'likes as likesCount', 'comments as commentsCount',
            'likes as isLiked' =>function($query){
                 $query->where('user_id', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : 0);
             }
        ]
    )
    ->find($post->id);
```

And now you get `likesCount` (int), `commentsCount` (int) and `isLiked` (boolean)